# Can't get phase 1 and 2 phaseId data from feed

Tags: chainlink

I'm getting historical data from the ETH/USD feed 0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419

There are currently 6 phases, but I can only fetch data if I start at phase 3. Is this because phase 1 and 2 has no data, or I'm doing something wrong ? I'm using the https://docs.chain.link/data-feeds/historical-data documentation, off-chain.

```
//this will iterate from the start of a given aggregator phase
func (ca *ChainlinkAggregatorV3Provider) iterateOverGivenPhase(phaseId int64 )error{

    roundId := ca.getPhaseStartRoundId(big.NewInt(phaseId),big.NewInt(1))
    err := ca.iterateRounds(roundId)

    return err
}
```

On phase 1 and 2, I simple get execution reverted, I'm expecting to get data from the first two phases as well